# Excel-DNA: grouping rows via C API feature of Excel-DNA

Tags: c#, excel, excel-dna

I'm familiar with how to group a range in Excel VSTO/COM interop:

```
ws.EnableOutlining = true;
ws.Outline.SummaryRow = XlSummaryRow.xlSummaryAbove;
var rng = GetRangeSomeHow();
rng.EntireRow.Group();
rng.EntireRow.OutlineLevel = someLevel;
```

What is the most efficient way to do this in Excel-DNA?  I would imagine there must be a C-API way to do it, encapsulated cleverly in Excel-DNA somehow, but for the life of me, I can't figure it out via online documentation (incl. Google).

There's a lot of posts using code similar to my sample above, but these are pretty expensive calls, especially since I need to do this ~5000 times overall (I have a really big data set).

**EDIT:**
So there seems to be this method call:

```
XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlfGroup...)
```

The only problem is, I have no idea what the parameters are. It seems an `ExcelReference` should be passed in, but how is the `.EntireRow` resolved? Will the C API just handle it for me - in which case I just need to pass a `new ExcelReference(1,100,1,1)` and be done with it... or is there more to this?

Thanks in advance to anyone who can answer my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the C API `GROUP` function is te one you're looking for. The documentation says:

> **GROUP**
>
> Creates a single object from several selected objects and returns the
>   object identifier of the group (for example, "Group 5"). Use GROUP to
>   combine a number of objects so that you can move or resize them
>   together.
>
> If no object is selected, only one object is selected, or a group is
>   already selected, GROUP returns the #VALUE! error value and interrupts
>   the macro.

I'd suggest you use the COM object model for this kind of thing, even in an Excel-DNA add-in. The C API has not really been updated over the years for the general sheet manipulation like this case, so you're likely to run into some features that don't work right or are incomplete relative to the COM object model.

From your Excel-DNA add-in, just make sure your get hold of the right Application root object with a call to `ExcelDnaUtil.Application`.

For improved performance of this kind of sheet editing, you pretty much have to use the same tricks as from VBA or VSTO - disable screen updating and calculations etc.

Comment: Thanks!  I can't upvote you yet, but this was very helpful.